# Prevent Receiving from Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

When photos are shared from Google Photos, if the recipient is a Gmail user, they are by default shared through Google Photos rather than email to the Gmail account. Is there any way to prevent people sharing to my Google Photos account. I need to receive a email along with the photo for documentation purposes.